# Proving a property about invertibility of matrices (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $n$ x $n$ matrices with the property that $$AB=-BA$$

Prove that if $n$ is odd then either $A$ or $B$ is not invertible.

What i tried

Proving by contradiction

We assume the negation of the statement $n$ is even and both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Since both $A$ and $B$ are invertible, then

$AB=I_{n}$

and

$BA=I_{n}$

Which means

$AB=BA$ which thus contradicts the fact that

$$AB=-BA$$

Hence proving the original statement. Is my proof correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Why do you state that $AB=I_n=BA$? The fact that $A$ and $B$ are invertible does not mean that $A$ must be the inverse of $B$.

.

You can start by assuming $A$ and $B$ are invertible and $AB=-BA$ and then proving that $n$ cannot be an even number.

Comment: Your method is not correct. Moreover you are assuming that $n$ is even when it is assumed that $n$ is odd (actually you are not using this assumption at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

By determinant's properties we have $\det(AB)=\det(BA)$ and
$$AB=-BA\quad\implies\quad\det (AB)=\det(-BA)=(-1)^n\det(BA)$$

Comment: Is my method of proving correct? Could u explain. Thanks